# Link to a .o file compiled in Ubuntu with cygwin

Tags: c++, windows, hyperlink, g++

I was given three .o files for a class.

f0.o
f1.o
f11.o

I do not know what's inside of them, all I know is that they have a function

eval(int *pj);

My task is to determine the maximum value of that function using a hill climber and a genetic algorithm

The .o files were compiled on ubuntu. I am running Windows 8 64-bit. I have downloaded cygwin32 bit and cygwin64 bit. The .o files are 32 bit.

I have tried to link them

g++ -std=c++11 f0.o main.o -lm

However, I get these errors (many others for f1.o and f11.o)

```
f0.o: In function `Z41__static_initialization_and_destruction_0ii':
f0.cpp:(.text+0x9c): undefined reference to `ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev'
f0.cpp:(.text+0xa1): undefined reference to `ZNSt8ios_base4InitD1Ev'
f0.cpp:(.text+0xa9): undefined reference to `_dso_handle'
f0.cpp:(.text+0xb9): undefined reference to `_cxa_atexit'
/tmp/ccdsysP1.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x4f): undefined reference to `eval(int*)'
```

I have tried googling these and am getting no reasonable results

Can anyone please tell me what's wrong?

Here is the code from main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double eval(int *pj);

int main()
{

  int vec[150];

  int i;

  for(i = 0; i < 150; i++){
    vec[i] = 1;
  }
  cout << eval(vec) << endl;
  //printf("Fitness = %lf\n", eval(vec));
}
```

Comment: Trying to link non-native libraries will only end in tears. You're *much* better off grabbing a copy of [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and installing Ubuntu in a little Virtual Machine :)

Comment: @KarlNicoll: It doesn't have to be a VM if you can get access to a system already running Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error `undefined reference to 'ZNSt8ios_base4InitC1Ev'` seems to indicate that the linker can't find a reference to [ios_base](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/ios_base).

Most like the reason for this is that the compiler/linker used to build your the object file you were given (probably gcc) and the compiler/linker used to build your program (mingw32/mingw64) have incompatible ABIs. That is, just like you can't link the output of MSVC with output of GCC, I think you need to use a compatible compiler to do it.

The obvious, guaranteed way to get it to work would be to simply build your program against the provided object file on Ubuntu in a virtual machine.

Cygwin may also work, however.

Comment: ah, I used cygwin, not mingw, my bad ;O, that was throwing those errors. The .o files were compiled with g++. There are also gcc versions. http://www.cse.unr.edu/~sushil/class/ai/index.html (assignment 2)

Comment: On my 64-bit linux machine, I downloaded f0.o, copy/pasted the code from your OP, and then ran `g++ -c so.cpp && g++ so.o f0.o -o so` and it worked just fine. Executing the resulting program prints out a number, as expected. Your compiler is definitely the problem - if cygwin and mingw32 don't work, then I'm afraid that a Ubuntu virtual machine is probably your only option.